# Possibility problems.

Tags: combinatorics

The questions ask: what are the possibility of picking a positive real number less than or equal to 3 from all the numbers less than  10, AND the possibility of picking a positive real number JUST LESS THAN 3 from all the numbers less than 10.

The part of the problem that troubles me is how to evenly divide up a range of numbers.

Comment: I just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of picking exactly 3 is zero. And

$$P(0< x\le 3) = P(0<x<3) + P(x=3) = P(0<x<3)+0$$

So they will have the same answer. Now what is the probability of picking a number in the interval $(0,3)$ given they you;re selecting from $(0,10]$?

Comment: 3/10 Right? Easy if it is equal to 10

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: But the problem is different

Comment: Do you mean $P(0<x\le 3 \ \text{and} \ 0<x< 3)$?

Comment: Or do you mean pick one number followed by picking another number?

Comment: Sorry it is less than 10

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the uniform distribution $u$ on $(0,10]$, it is respectively
  $$u((0,3]) = \int_{(0,3]} u(dx) = \int_{(0,3]} \frac{dx}{10} = \frac{3}{10} $$
and
  $$u((0,3)) = \int_{(0,3)} u(dx) = \int_{(0,3)} \frac{dx}{10} = \frac{3}{10}\;. $$
This is the same probability, as the difference is just the probability to pick *exactly* 3, which is an event of probability 0.

Comment: Why does the probability of 3 equal 0?

Comment: The uniform distribution on $(0,10]$ puts 0 probability on any singleton, finite set, or even countable sets. (You have uncountably many elements in $(0,10]$, each of them having "the same probability of appearing": each fixed element has probability 0, but the probability of an interval $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$ is $b-a$)

Comment: Technically it is close to zero right?

Comment: No, exactly zero.